# I am writing a program for converting DNA to protein, I am not get idea to creat help me to get through it,

Tags: python, bioinformatics

```
def translat_dna(sequence):
    gencode= {
        'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M',
        'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
        'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
        'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',                 
        'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L',
        'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
        'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
        'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
        'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V',
        'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
        'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
        'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
        'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S',
        'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
        'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'_', 'TAG':'_',
        'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'_', 'TGG':'W',
    }
    proteinseq=''
    for n in range(0,len(gencode),3):
        if sequence[n:n+3] in gencode:
            proteinseq += gencode[sequence[n:n+3]:
            sequence=''
                return proteinseq in translat_dna()
```

Comment: What do you want to do? What is wrong with what you have? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for n in range(0,len(gencode),3):
```

Onto:

```
for n in range(0,len(sequence),3):
```

Comment: I done What you have show but still it's showing an error message

Comment: Will you show us error message? And may be sample code generating it?

Answer (score 1):

```
def translat_dna(sequence):
    gencode = {
        'ATA': 'I', 'ATC': 'I', 'ATT': 'I', 'ATG': 'M',
        'ACA': 'T', 'ACC': 'T', 'ACG': 'T', 'ACT': 'T',
        'AAC': 'N', 'AAT': 'N', 'AAA': 'K', 'AAG': 'K',
        'AGC': 'S', 'AGT': 'S', 'AGA': 'R', 'AGG': 'R',
        'CTA': 'L', 'CTC': 'L', 'CTG': 'L', 'CTT': 'L',
        'CCA': 'P', 'CCC': 'P', 'CCG': 'P', 'CCT': 'P',
        'CAC': 'H', 'CAT': 'H', 'CAA': 'Q', 'CAG': 'Q',
        'CGA': 'R', 'CGC': 'R', 'CGG': 'R', 'CGT': 'R',
        'GTA': 'V', 'GTC': 'V', 'GTG': 'V', 'GTT': 'V',
        'GCA': 'A', 'GCC': 'A', 'GCG': 'A', 'GCT': 'A',
        'GAC': 'D', 'GAT': 'D', 'GAA': 'E', 'GAG': 'E',
        'GGA': 'G', 'GGC': 'G', 'GGG': 'G', 'GGT': 'G',
        'TCA': 'S', 'TCC': 'S', 'TCG': 'S', 'TCT': 'S',
        'TTC': 'F', 'TTT': 'F', 'TTA': 'L', 'TTG': 'L',
        'TAC': 'Y', 'TAT': 'Y', 'TAA': '_', 'TAG': '_',
        'TGC': 'C', 'TGT': 'C', 'TGA': '_', 'TGG': 'W',
    }
    proteinseq = ''
    for n in range(0, len(sequence), 3):
        proteinseq += gencode.get(sequence[n:n + 3], '')
    return proteinseq
```

You could also shorten it slightly using `str.join`:

```
def translat_dna(sequence):
    gencode = {
        'ATA': 'I', 'ATC': 'I', 'ATT': 'I', 'ATG': 'M',
        'ACA': 'T', 'ACC': 'T', 'ACG': 'T', 'ACT': 'T',
        'AAC': 'N', 'AAT': 'N', 'AAA': 'K', 'AAG': 'K',
        'AGC': 'S', 'AGT': 'S', 'AGA': 'R', 'AGG': 'R',
        'CTA': 'L', 'CTC': 'L', 'CTG': 'L', 'CTT': 'L',
        'CCA': 'P', 'CCC': 'P', 'CCG': 'P', 'CCT': 'P',
        'CAC': 'H', 'CAT': 'H', 'CAA': 'Q', 'CAG': 'Q',
        'CGA': 'R', 'CGC': 'R', 'CGG': 'R', 'CGT': 'R',
        'GTA': 'V', 'GTC': 'V', 'GTG': 'V', 'GTT': 'V',
        'GCA': 'A', 'GCC': 'A', 'GCG': 'A', 'GCT': 'A',
        'GAC': 'D', 'GAT': 'D', 'GAA': 'E', 'GAG': 'E',
        'GGA': 'G', 'GGC': 'G', 'GGG': 'G', 'GGT': 'G',
        'TCA': 'S', 'TCC': 'S', 'TCG': 'S', 'TCT': 'S',
        'TTC': 'F', 'TTT': 'F', 'TTA': 'L', 'TTG': 'L',
        'TAC': 'Y', 'TAT': 'Y', 'TAA': '_', 'TAG': '_',
        'TGC': 'C', 'TGT': 'C', 'TGA': '_', 'TGG': 'W',
    }
    return ''.join(gencode.get(sequence[n:n + 3], '')
                   for n in range(0, len(sequence), 3))
```

Comment: thanks for your help it works well , how to access the text file which has the fast formate of DNA

Comment: @hemantcnaik Could you upload the text file to something like bpaste.net so I could see it? I’m just not sure what the format looks like. Chances are you are just going to want to use pythons built in ‘open’ function though.